# Image Picker always uses rear camera by default

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [ImagePicker v0.6.7+1](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker) plugin to prompt the user to take a selfie with Flutter

```
 await new ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);
```

The above code opens the Rear camera by default instead of the front camera (Samsung Galaxy Note 8 Edge )

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-MU)
```

Comment: There seems to be an open issue for this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55644

Answer (score 0):

There's a limitation on Android for handling camera intent which the `image_picker` plugin uses. The parameter only works on some devices as mentioned as mentioned on this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55644#issuecomment-691079453).

Comment: yes, if u check on the code u will find this doc too. they said
"It is also ignored if the chosen camera is not supported on the device."